# delete journal entries counter data in odoo 12

Tags: postgresql, odoo, accounting

I needed to move the old database with all its setting from one server to another, and then remove the accounting testing data, I was able to delete journal items, journal entries and invoices but couldn't make the counter equals zero.
as shown in the picture next to the journal entries:

[image]

I need to setup Odoo system for the production. I don't want to make a new database as it needs a lot of data entry.

Comment: Do you mean the number `21` in your picture? That's the database ID of that entry and if you want to reset the ID sequence of the `account_move` table, you have to do that in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `REINDEX` maintenance operation on your database to reset table id.

Or you can reset the table (`Journal entries`) id with the following SQL query:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE account_move_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```